# Unable to make Airflow DAG run at a specific time every day

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to schedule an Airflow DAG but unable to do so successfully. I have a valid start date. I want to schedule it to run every morning at 5:30 AM but I have had to manually trigger it the last couple of days.

Here´s what my schedule interval looks like: `schedule_interval='30 5 0 0 0'`. I have also tried it with a different syntax like this: `schedule_interval='30 5 * * *'`, but couldn´t make it work. Below is my complete code:

```
default_dag_args = {
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 15),
}

with models.DAG(
        'data_dump',
        schedule_interval='30 5 0 0 0',
        default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:
  
    hello = bash_operator.BashOperator(
            task_id='hello',
            bash_command='echo Hello.')

    goodbye_bash = bash_operator.BashOperator(
        task_id='bye',
        bash_command='echo Goodbye.')

    hello >> goodbye_bash
```

I am starting to wonder, does `schedule_interval` have anything to do with time zones. Currently I am using Airflow with Cloud Composer environment set in `europe-west1-b`.

I need help in figuring out what´s wrong with my code and how to schedule a DAG correctly and would appreciate your response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The correct syntax is definitely `30 5 * * *`. If you have 2020-9-15 as start_date, the first DAG run actually happens shortly before 2020-09-16 05:30. Look [here](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/scheduling-tasks/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@philipp-johannis is correct, `30 5 * * *` is the correct `scheduler_interval`.

You can test with an older `start_date` as follows:

```py
with models.DAG(
        'data_dump',
        schedule_interval='30 5 0 0 0',
        start_date=datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 1)) as dag:
```